# Whether the decimal of usdt is 6？

Tags: erc-20

I noticed the decimal of usdt is 6. That means the constructor parameter is 6 for decimal.
How do I deal with it in ethers.js?

Comment: where do you need to deal with it? your questions need more clarity, please :)

Answer (score 1):

A BigNumber is an immutable object which allow accurate math operations on values larger than [JavaScript can accurately handle](https://docs.ethers.io/ethers.js/html/notes.html#ieee754).

In order to deal with it in ethers.js, we have a library under utils, which is the BigNumber library.

[ethers.js/Big Numbers](https://docs.ethers.io/ethers.js/html/api-utils.html#big-numbers)

**Example**

```
> let gasPriceWei = utils.bigNumberify("20902747399")
> gasPriceWei
BigNumber { _hex: '0x04dde69d07' }
> let gasLimit = utils.bigNumberify(3000000);
> gasLimit
BigNumber { _hex: '0x2dc6c0' }
> let maxCostWei = gasPriceWei.mul(gasLimit)
> maxCostWei
BigNumber { _hex: '0xdec8d064a42f40' }
> console.log("Max Cost: " + maxCostWei.toString());
Max Cost: 62708242197000000
```

Comment: What on earth has that got to do with the decimal of usdt being 6?????

Comment: For example: usdt decimal 6 will ultimately be stored in some contract. In order to retrieve it from the contract, the returned value will be a BigNumber. Then comes the question of dealing usdt 6 using ethers.js' utils BigNumber library. Thus, the above answer.

Comment: The question is highly unfocused, and it is not really clear what exactly the problem is,  with that I agree. For example, is it about `decimals` being 6 rather than some other value like the "standard" 18? Or is it perhaps about the `decimals` getter returning a BigNumber object? Or is it something else? Since `6` is explicitly mentioned, I would go with the first option. You've chosen to go with the second option, which IMO has very little chances of being actually related to the problem at hand.

Comment: You've essentially given a solution to a general issue which is not specifically related neither to `decimals` nor to the fact that it is set as `6`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on the answer, I think Louis can tell us about the purpose of their question.

Comment: I sincerely doubt that he will. He's already posted here a dozen of similarly-poor questions (a single-line statement with no technical details whatsoever in order to elaborate on the context).